# mysql: list all relation view related to column in a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

How to list all relation (**Foreign key**) of a column in a table? Say I have table **user**, with PK **user_id**, and I want to know all tables related to this table using the PK column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the SQL statement to get the details for all the foreign key for given PK (table_name, column_name). Hopefully, it works for you.

```
SELECT  TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
  WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'user'
    AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME ='user_id'
```

Comment: Optionally you can add the database name condition as well as:  TABLE_SCHEMA='testdb1' in where condition